# adding extra property ActiveRecord for enabling custom filter column in CgridView

Tags: php, activerecord, filter, yii, cgridview

I have a gridView in my program which it's data are populated with my ActiveRecord model.according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857861/1570631) I added some extra properties in my ActiveRecord to enable adding extra filtering column.
My queston is that is this a right way for doing such things.I mean adding some property which can not be matched with database table fields.
If not whcih approaches can be  used in these scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing bad with adding a property that doesn't match a database field. It's widely used approach and you can rely on it. Here's [an example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/) from yii wiki.